# How to use expo-background-fetch to fetch a specific url every 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, background-fetch

I have tried almost any example provided in docs but I can't run it.
I want to make a request to a specific url with axios (or fetch method) every 60 seconds and process the data in the background. In other words I want something common like:

```
this.getPageInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const json = await (await fetch(this.fetchURL)).json();
    ...// etc

}, 60000)
```

can happen when the app is in background.

my console.log says 'task registered' but it feels like this block of code never triggers(global scope):

```
BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(5);
const taskName = 'test-background-fetch';
TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, async () => {
    console.log('background fetch running');
    try {
        const receivedNewData = await (await fetch(this.fetchUri)).json();
        console.log('receivedNewData', receivedNewData) 
        return receivedNewData ? BackgroundFetch.Result.NewData : BackgroundFetch.Result.NoData;

        let isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(taskName);
        console.log("isRegistered: ", isRegistered);

    } catch (error) {
        return BackgroundFetch.Result.Failed;
    }
    console.log("BackgroundFetch.Result.NewData", BackgroundFetch.Result.NewData);
    return BackgroundFetch.Result.NewData;
});
```

and in my class component:

```
await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(taskName, {
        setMinimumIntervalAsync: 5,
        stopOnTerminate: false
    });
    await BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(5);
    alert('task registered');
    console.log('task registered');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not registering your task in your class component. Is taskname defined as 'test-background-fetch' in your component? You need to call exactly the same task name.

Also some phones are somewhat problematic with background tasks. I never tried it on expo, but on React Native some brands had to go through some extra setup.

Also note that in the documentation it says it only works when *backgrounded*. *Terminated* apps wont run the background function.